# Hawking-Page Phase Transition for Charged AdS Black Holes

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, ads-cft

My question is concerned with the vacuum state of charged black holes in a Hawking-Page type phase transition.

> Is the vacuum of a charged AdS$_d$ black hole a pure AdS$_d$ spacetime or an AdS$_d$ spacetime with charge?

The [Chamblin, Emparan, Johnson, Myers](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902170) series of papers don't mention the vacuum state explicitly other than it being AdS.